# downmix to mono on Linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, mono, mixer

I need to downmix from stereo to mono (my system only has one speaker) on a raspberry pi running runeaudio. I tried to apply the solution here [Force downmix to mono on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/155522/force-downmix-to-mono-on-linux/1185557) but it does not work in my situation.

speaker-test gives following error. Can you tell me what's wrong?

> speaker-test -Dmakemono -c2 -t wav
>
> speaker-test 1.1.0
>
> Playback device is makemono Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2
>   channels WAV file(s) Broken configuration for playback: no
>   configurations available: Invalid argument Setting of hwparams failed:
>   Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

This looks as if your hardware does not support mono playback.

To downmix to both channels, try something like this:

```
pcm.makemono {
    type route
    slave.pcm "hw:0"
    ttable {
        0.0 1
        0.1 1
        1.0 1
        1.1 1
    }
}
```